# Sort SPQuotaTemplateCollection based on size using c#

Tags: sharepoint-server, development

We don't have inbuilt function to sort Site Templates based on size hence we will get random size site templates. When we do auto upgrade site template it may cause the issue because random order.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution please check below.

```
SPWebApplication spWebApp = this.WebApplication;
//get all quota templates
SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
SPQuotaTemplateCollection quotaTemplates = contentService.QuotaTemplates;
//Sorting quota templates
List<SPQuotaTemplate> _sortQuotaTemplates = sortQuotaTemplates(quotaTemplates);


private List<SPQuotaTemplate> sortQuotaTemplates(SPQuotaTemplateCollection quotaTemplates)
        {
            List<SPQuotaTemplate> _quotaTemplatesList = new List<SPQuotaTemplate>();

            foreach (SPQuotaTemplate item in quotaTemplates)
            {
                _quotaTemplatesList.Add(item);
            }

            _quotaTemplatesList.Sort((x, y) => x.StorageMaximumLevel.CompareTo(y.StorageMaximumLevel));

            return _quotaTemplatesList;
        }
```